# Creating a custom search engine with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, search-engine

I need to create a search engine that will retrieve records from the database. I've done some searching but didn't find anything that can point me to a good starting point.

Say there's a record with a title of "Swimming in a river with Sally". When I search for "Swimming with Sally" or "Sally Swimming", the record "Swimming in a river with Sally" will be shown.

I'd appreciate if learning resources can be provided.

Comment: Please consider searching the stackoverflow threads and other mediums before posting a question. Additionally make sure you post a question, showing what you have tried.

Comment: You mean like google?

Answer (score 0):

Use **Ajax AutoComplete extender** control.

```
  <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">  
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Link:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_AutoComplete_simple.ashx